# Would it be possible to embed busybox binary or Termux's apt in a Android app?

Tags: android

Termux comes with busybox and apt and is opensource.  In Termux you can run:

`$ apt-get install xyz`

I would like to embed this functionality in my app. The end goal is being able to install openssh server via apt. With Termux openssh server can be installed and run, as non-root, by the following:

`$ apt-get update`

`$ apt-get install openssh`

`$ sshd`

Termux packages are available via https://github.com/termux/termux-packages My question is how easy would it be to include/embed a subset of these packages in an android app to accomplish the aforementioned task?

Comment: See: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/559#issuecomment-519991927